# Where magento 2 send mail, when create customer from admin

Tags: magento2, customer, email, email-templates

Anybody know where magento 2 in adminhtml customer creation, get email template, put it in transport builder, and send mail to customer with cunfirmation link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following class:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php

```
protected function sendEmailConfirmation(CustomerInterface $customer, $redirectUrl)
{
    try {
        $hash = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId())->getPasswordHash();
        $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED;
        if ($this->isConfirmationRequired($customer) && $hash != '') {
            $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION;
        } elseif ($hash == '') {
            $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NO_PASSWORD;
        }
        $this->getEmailNotification()->newAccount($customer, $templateType, $redirectUrl, $customer->getStoreId());
        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
    } catch (MailException $e) {
        // If we are not able to send a new account email, this should be ignored
        $this->logger->critical($e);
    } catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e);
    }
}
```

The following line is sent email template for resetting the password:

> $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NO_PASSWORD;